# How to add EMR steps using terraform

Tags: terraform

I need to add EMR steps via terraform when creating my EMR using terraform since I need to disable "keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps" . How can I do that

Answer (score 2):

To add steps to your EMR cluster you can add a steps section in your EMR resource.

Provided you have the following lines in your "my-bootstrap.sh" file to download a steps bash file from S3:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/steps.sh /tmp/steps.sh
chmod +x /tmp/steps.sh
```

You could launch both bootstrap actions and steps with the following aws_emr_cluster configuration:

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "my-emr-cluster" {
  name                              = "my-emr-cluster"
  release_label                     = "emr-5.9.0"

  ...

  bootstrap_action {
    path = "s3://my-bucket/my-bootstrap.sh"
    name = "my-emr-bootstrap"
  }

  step {
    action_on_failure = "CANCEL_AND_WAIT"
    name   = "Download S3 files to HDFS"
    hadoop_jar_step {
      jar  = "command-runner.jar"
      args = ["bash", "/tmp/steps.sh"]
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Also, and as Fionn says, there is no need to add steps if you just want to enable/disable `keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps`.

Answer (score 0):

To disable `keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps` on EMR you do not need to add the Steps itself but only the cluster.

[Here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps) you can finde the documentation in the Terraform documentation

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified what kind of jobs you deploying, I can suggest having a look at [emrstreaming](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/b-b3rn4rd/emrstreaming/latest/docs) terraform provider. The emrstreaming provider offers continuous deployment functionality for streaming steps into an EMR cluster.
Usage example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    emrstreaming = {
      source = "b-b3rn4rd/emrstreaming"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the EMRStreaming Provider
provider "emrstreaming" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

resource "emrstreaming_step" "step_example" {
  cluster_id = "j-xxxxxxxxxx"
  step = {
    hadoop_jar_step = {
      args = [
        "spark-submit",
        "--name", "example-app",
        "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
        "--master", "yarn",
        "--driver-cores", 2,
        "--conf", "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
        "--conf", "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=app-site-packages",
        "s3://example-bucket-name/example-app/main.py"
      ]
      jar = "command-runner.jar"
    }
    health_check_monitor_period = 120
    name                        = "example-app"
    force_redeploy              = true
    pre_shutdown_wait_period    = 10
    shutdown_timeout            = 60
  }
}
```